# Disprove that "if $p$ is a prime number, then $2^p-1$ is also a prime number"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

We can see manually that $2^p-1$ is not prime. As $2047$ is not a prime. $2^{11} = 2048$.

But I'm unable to figure out a formal way of disproving the statement.

Comment: This is a formal proof (but you should provide a factorization of 2047).

Comment: Disproving a general statement by demonstrating a counterexample is as formal as anything I know.

Comment: In other words, congratulations!  You've won.

Comment: A fact that you may find interesting is that Lagrange's theorem from elementary group theory implies that all the prime factors $q$ of $2^p-1$ ($p$ a prime) must satisfy the congruence $q\equiv1\pmod{2p}$. Observe that this works in your example case as well:
$2047=23\cdot89$ and both $23$ and $89$ leave remainder $1$ when divided by $2p=22$.

Comment: @Stefan ... or some other proof that 2047 is not prime.

Comment: @Joffan What other proofs other than factorization, can you mention them please?

Comment: eg. $622^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 2047 \implies 2047$ is not prime - essentially, failing a Miller-Rabin prime test.

Comment: Or this could be shown as an example of the Lucas-Lehmer test at work: https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove3_2.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've demonstrated a counterexample, so it is a formal proof.

All you need to write is something like "The statement is false: p=11 is a prime, but $2^{11} - 1= 23 \times 89$ is not prime."

Trying lots of cases is a valid technique to disprove something (but not necessarily to prove something unless you can do a complete exhaustive search or show a reduction to a set where you can exhaustively search; a decent number of combinatorics/algebra proofs have been done by reducing to a set of (many) cases and then exhaustively checking those cases via computer).

Answer (score 6):

To disprove an assertion that is false, a single counterexample suffices, and in this particular case, you've already provided it: $$2^{11} - 1 = 2047 = 23 \times 89.$$

This is formal enough. For professional mathematicians, the simplest, minimal way to accomplish the goal is the best way, as evidenced in the old joke about the mathematician who escaped what Houdini could not by redefining "inside" and "outside."

But if you want, you can add some additional remarks and make it formal by prefacing it with the word "remark." For example:

> **Remark.** The largest known Mersenne prime as of this writing is $2^{74207281} - 1$, which is believed to be the $49^{\textrm{th}}$ Mersenne prime. Given that $74207281$ is the $4350601^{\textrm{st}}$ prime, this suggests that almost any prime $p$ will fail to give a prime of the form $2^p - 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible general proof:

**If prime numbers are randomly distributed, as is widely and strongly believed**, then $x=2^p-1=prime$ is false.

Proof:

Assume $p_s$ is the smallest possible prime. Then, $x=2^{p_{s}}- 1$ **must be the next prime**. This means that $x$ determines the next prime in the sequence and so forth. **This contradicts the fundamental belief that prime numbers are randomly distributed**.

If a prime number lies between $p_s$ and $x=2^{p_{s}}- 1$, then this contradicts $p_s$ being the smallest prime because something smaller than $p_s$ would have to construct that interim prime. Also, something smaller than $p_s$ would have to exist in order to construct $p_s$ via the same pattern.

Comment: Interesting explanation. But what is the guarantee that (2^p)-1 is the only pattern to get a prime number. It doesn't say so in the question. We could have say another pattern which gives that intermediate prime number. However, I like your idea. Let me know if I made a mistake in my assumption that it may not be the only prime number generator.

Comment: @aste123 If there is any pattern at all to the primes, then the primes aren't randomly distributed.

Comment: Yes, as a whole, there can't be any patterns. So, what if (2^p)-1 gives some of the prime numbers. And there are a lot more than these. Thus, the randomness on a whole is still maintained?
I understand if you are trying to say that even if a formula can give a new prime number although not the immediate next in the series, then the randomness is broken in some way. I agree with that.

However, it feels a bit tentative to me because the result of the proof itself should reinforce the randomness instead of using the "perception" that prime numbers are random to prove the conjecture.

Comment: @aste123 I added the last sentence. Am I wrong to assume that the "pattern formula" must also produce the smallest prime, therefore it can't be the smallest?

Comment: But why does every number in the class have to depend on one of the previous numbers (No where it is written that the formula has to generate all the possible prime numbers)? Let's say the first two are independent.  Similarly, the formula 2x will always generate a positive integer if x is a positive integer but this doesn't mean that all numbers that belong to positive integer class get generated.

Comment: Statistical arguments in number theory can be useful, but are never a proof. Goldbach's conjecture is not proven, although for statistical reasons, it "must" be true. Moreover, why should $2^{p_s}-1$ be the next prime starting with $p_s$ ?

Comment: @Peter and aste123 -  According to the problem statement aste123 provided, is it incorrect to assume that if X is a prime number, then P (a prime) can be found such that $X = 2^p-1$?

Comment: Very good answer, upvote from me. However, Sheldon Cooper would complain that $r$ and $m$ are undefined symbols, and ask if $i$ is the imaginary unit and $e$ the natural log base. In any case it might look better to define $\mathbb{P}$ or $\mathcal{P}$ as the set of primes among the positive integers. Or you can always use `\textrm`.

Comment: @Inquisitive It seemed more like single implication to me than double implication. And that's how I had perceived it. However, I liked your answer and have upvoted it too.

Comment: @aste123 Thanks. I appreciate it. I'm no mathematician, but I love all math, particularly number theory.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Sorry, but I do not see how Inquisitive's answer disproves in any way the claim $p\ prime\implies 2^p-1\ prime$. At least, it should be clarified what "next prime" means in this context (obviously not the prime following after $p_s$).

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$, such that $2p+1$ is also prime, it can be proven that $2p+1|2^p-1$.

So you have a family of primes being a counterexample to the claim.

It is conjectured, but not proven, that infinite many primes $p=4k+3$ exist, such that $2p+1$ is also prime.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do a proof by contradiction (which in this case would only be a more formal way to phrase your proof).

In this method you start by assuming that the opposite of what you want to prove is true (in our case, assuming that $2^p - 1$ is a prime). Given what we know, 2047 should be prime, because it follows the form of $2^p - 1$.

However, we can see that:

> $2^{11} - 1 = 2048 - 1 = 2047$

We know 2047 is not a prime number, because 2047 = 23 * 89.

Now we have reached the contradiction part of the proof. According to our assumption in the beginning of the proof, any number of the form $2^p - 1$ should be prime. We have just shown this assumption to lead to a contradiction, and thus we must abandon this assumption as false.

Comment: Proof by contradiction seems to add an extraneous layer to what should be a simple answer.

Comment: It's a proof style that is common. For this case it adds nothing useful, but OP wanted something formal and proof by contradiction is nothing if not formal.